# mount.cifs stopped working after last kernel upgrade

Tags: 12.04, kernel, mount, cifs

Yesterday (05/21) I upgraded my Ubuntu 12.04 kernel:

`uname -a`:

```
Linux vi 3.2.0-24-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 25 08:43:22 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

After the reboot all my mounts of external Samba shares stopped working.

When I execute:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.101.168/video /mnt/video
```

The result is:

```
mount error: cifs filesystem not supported by the system
mount error(19): No such device
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

And dmesg shows:

```
[ 2785.792456] cifs: Unknown symbol locks_delete_block (err 0)
```

If I execute:

```
sudo modprobe cifs
```

The result is:

```
FATAL: Error inserting cifs (/lib/modules/3.2.0-24-generic/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko): Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)
```

And dmesg shows again:

```
[ 5811.742563] cifs: Unknown symbol locks_delete_block (err 0)
```

Is there any known workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

I would try to reinstall smbfs:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install cifs-utils
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. but it did not work.

Comment: Have you tried a full update?, as in `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: @GustavoV. The package should be called `cifs-utils` not `smbfs`, try re installing `cifs-utils` as sugested here and shoot any errors in to your question if you see them

Comment: I updated the answer with the correct package. I always get confused between those.

Comment: I am still checking the full update... one minute please.

Comment: I tried both: no changes (same errors)

Comment: ... neither reinstall nor full update produced any errors or warning.

Comment: Does this file exist, /lib/modules/3.2.0-24-generic/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko?

Comment: Yes: -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 503816 may  1 18:59 /lib/modules/3.2.0-24-generic/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko

Comment: Well, Im at a loss, that's what mine is too `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 503816 May  1 12:59 /lib/modules/3.2.0-24-generic/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko`

Comment: Thanks reverendj1, I assume your kernel is the same as mine too.

Comment: It is, but mine says #38, and I'm not exactly sure what that number is referring to: `Linux hol-w-johnw1 3.2.0-24-generic #38-Ubuntu SMP Tue May 1 16:18:50 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`. Also, I regularly use Samba shares too and they seem to be working fine.

Comment: That is a clue. My kernel looks a bit older.

Comment: ... please give me some time to look for your kernel on another Ubuntu repository.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to reboot? I really, really hate asking that about Linux, but it fixed it for me.

Comment: Thanks, you can see above that the problem was a bit harder to resolve.

Comment: Every time I upgrade my kernel, I have to reboot before my CIFS mounts will work.

Do you happen to know _why_ a reboot fixes this? [Also, reloading the module in question seems to fail silently.]

It'd be great if I could work around this without a reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstall `cifs-utils` and reboot. This works for me.

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install cifs-utils && sudo reboot
```

Comment: The reinstall is immaterial. It's the reboot that's important.

Comment: You can see bellow that reverendj1 made the same suggestion yesterday. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Please don't script a reboot into anything you post somewhere like this. People will copy and paste without thinking and then accidentally reboot their server.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved!

While trying to resolve this issue I broke my computer's GRUB. I could not find time to restore the system until an hour ago, so please, excuse me for the delay in my answer.

Thanks a lot, reverendj1 & Bruno!

reverendj1: The different kernel version was the correct clue, it produced the missing symbol in cifs.ko.

The problem, incredibly, was the consequence of an undetected USB disk: The one I use to boot Ubuntu up on a RAID.

As Ubuntu fails to mount the USB disk (that I have on fstab mounted to /boot), it creates a dummy /boot on the raid that of course does not exist during startup phase at BIOS, but it is the only one that exist during normal computer operation.

As I updated the kernel, the updated kernel (#38) was written to the dummy boot. The "real" (during startup) kernel (the older #37) remained in the external USB disk that is visible only during startup.

The only effect that I could perceive from this kernel mismatch was that the cifs driver could not load.